# How to get the column and row number of a cell in Excel Python using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I'm trying to get the column number and row number of the cell from which the function was called or of the cell which was passed inside the function code in Excel.

If I'm calling a user defined function(UDF) in excel like,`=some_udf(A2:D2)` and at the backend, i.e. where the definitions of this function are written in python using xlwings, I want to get the cell row number and column number from which this function was called or maybe get that using the range passed as argument. I'm unable to figure out how to do this.

Please help!
Or if it's possible using some other tools like openpyxl, etc, do tell.

Answer (score 0):

When you call user-defined functions with xlwings, you can include the special parameter `caller` in your function definition which will be your range object from which you called the function:

```py
@xw.func
def some_udf(your_arg, caller):
    # caller will not be exposed in Excel, so use it like so:
    # =some_udf(your_arg)
    # Now you can access infos about the caller, e.g.:
    caller.address
    caller.row
    caller.column
```

See also: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#the-caller-argument